# Determining content from StreamReader?

Tags: c#, stream, io, .net

I am forced to work with a crappy 3rd party API where there is no consistency with the return type. So I submit a programmatic web request, grab the Stream back and the underlying content might be an error message (worse still because it can be either raw text, or xml they return) or it returns a binary file. I have no means of knowing what format to expect with any given request so I need a way to introspect this at runtime.

How should I go about tackling this? The stream is non-seekable so I can't do anything other than read it. I usually try not to use exception handling for flow control but it seems like that might be the best way to handle it. Always treat it like it should be the expected binary file type and if anything blows up then catch the exception and try to extract what should be an error message

Comment: Q: Can you at least open the first 256 bytes (or heck - just the first *four* bytes)?, then go back and process the *entire* stream (based on what you find in the "header")?

Comment: If this 3rd party API is publicly available, please name it, so I'll never use it.

Comment: no Paul, since its non-seekable its forward-only and read-only, the best I could do is read the first kb into a buffer then discard the stream, then inspect the buffer and try to figure out what it is and then re-issue the request if its binary content. But all that does is make it a double request every time, I think its better to just let it blow up

Comment: @snappymcsnap no need for that - you just buffer some, figure out what you want, then process from the buffer and the stream. Since you need t process it in chunks anyway, that isn't any different.

Comment: The other option, of course, is to write the stream to a temp file, then process the file (seekable).

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to mind is to examine the first x number of bytes in the stream.  If  the first bit is well formed xml, then it's probably xml.  The problem is trying to determine the difference between raw text or binary.

Comment: The first few bytes could be a BOM... And just identifying XML is only a very small part of handling arbitrary data